# Why is my mouse cursor jumpy?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mouse

I use a [Logitech MK270 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo](https://amzn.to/3hn7oTT) plugged into [AUKEY USB C to USB 3.0 Adapter](https://amzn.to/3b2jxLE).

It works totally fine for my Win 10 PC. But when I switch to use the mouse/keyboard with my "[2019 Apple MacBook Pro](https://amzn.to/3EUsaE1) (16-inch, 16GB RAM, 512GB Storage) – Space Gray MVVJ2LL/A CR", its cursor is sometimes very frustratingly jumpy.

This is even with the USB nub receiver only 50 cm from the mouse.

I use the Mac with its lid closed, and a USB-C cable to my 42.5" Dell monitor is what drives the display (and provides power to the Mac).

The cursor only skips around the screen while I'm moving the mouse. It doesn't randomly jump while the mouse is still.

I never have these problems on my PC, even when the USB nub is further from the mouse. So the mouse hardware is fine.

Update: Today, the wireless keyboard started occasionally lagging too.

Comment: Bad link to AUKEY adapter. Perhaps [this one?](http://old.aukey.com/products/usb-3-0-usb-a-to-usb-c-adapters-2-pack-cb-a1-2) Have you tried all USBC ports on the MBP?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, that is the AUKEY adapter. And yes, I've tried the MBP's different ports. Thanks.

Comment: The keyboard lag is driving me crazy.

Comment: Both Aukey links don't work. I suggest you purchase a different USBC Adapter!

Comment: Although my question was originally about the mouse, these days the keyboard is way more problematic. I don't think the USB-C adapter is likely to be at fault since the webcam and mouse plugged into it aren't having problems when the keyboard does. From https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/16-macbook-pro-lagging-whilst-typing.2300340/?post=30002596#post-30002596 I'm worried that maybe Macbooks are just bad. And it's true. I did need to have Apple replace one of these already. That whole "support" experience was a nightmare.